# I am modelling a time series, the results are coming fine without exogenous variables but predictions are getting wrong on including exog varaibles

Tags: time-series, forecasting, autoregressive, moving-average, exogeneity

I am modelling a time series, the results are coming fine without exogenous variables but predictions are getting wrong on including exog varaibles, the forecasting series is starting from a lower value

[image: This is the result I got using SARIMAX (3,1,0)(0,1,0,12) without using exogs]

[image: This result I got after including exog variables using SARIMAX (3,1,0)(0,1,0,12), the learning seems to be fine but prediction is starting at a lower value, can some please explain how to interpret the result of exogs and what hyperparameter tunning can be done]

[image: The data is monthly and these are the ACF and PACF plots]

Comment: @Richard Hardy sir please help.

Comment: Do you mean when you add exogenous variables you predict less well?

Comment: In the 2nd image, orange is predicted and green is actual, as it can be seen for 2019 the predicted values are way lesser then actuals and for 2020 it is much higher then actuals.